# Inoic 3, Android: How to only allow number input field?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have input field like this:

`.html` file:

```
<ion-input formControlName="codePin" 
           type="tel" 
           pattern="[0-9]*" 
           class="itemBorder" 
           placeholder="Only number" 
           maxlength="4" 
           style="-webkit-text-security:disc"
           [(ngModel)]="codePin" (keydown)="isValidNumber($event)">
</ion-input>
```

`.ts` file:

```
isValidNumber(event)
{
    //return /\d|Backspace/.test(event.key);
    if ([8, 13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.keyCode) > -1) {
        // backspace, enter, escape, arrows
        return true;
    } else if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
        // numbers 0 to 9
        return true;
    } else if (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) {
        // numpad number
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is, that it runs Ok in Ionic Serve's Lab, IOS, but it is not working in Android. Anyone please explain to me how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: What does not working mean? What error do you get? What would you like help with? Please elaborate

Comment: In Ionic serve or IOS, This input will not allow me to type a non Number key, but in android, I could type any key in this Input. I dont know why this func cant run in Android. Im a newbie mobile coder @@

Comment: If you only want numbers you can change the input type `type="number"`

Comment: @arkade type= "number" doesnt allow 0 number  if in put like 0123.

Comment: interesting .. did not know that